# Prove/disprove: $f+g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $x_0$ $\implies$ $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Prove/disprove: $f+g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $x_0$ $\implies$ $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$

*attempt*

Suppose $g$ is not differentiable at $x_0$. There are three cases:
**Case I:** The two following one-sided limits exist, but not equal.$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}^+}\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}\neq \lim_{x\to {x_0}^-}\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$**Case II:** $g$ is not continuous at $x_0$
**Case III:** $g$ is undefined at $x_0$

Case I: $$\lim_{x\to {x_0}^-}\frac{(f+g)(x)-(f+g)(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to {x_0}^-}\Big(\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}+\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}\Big)=\lim_{x\to {x_0}^-}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}+\lim_{x\to {x_0}^-}\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}=L_f+L_{g^-}$$Similarly, with the other one-sided limit:$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}^+}\Big(...\Big)=...=L_f+L_{g^+}$$

Case II: For every type of discontinuity of $g$ we use one-sided limit rules and continuity of $f$ to show that $f+g$ is not continuous and therefore not differentiable.

Case III: That leads to $f+g$ being undefined at $x_0$.

*comment*
I haven't yet found a counterexample. If this idea of a proof works, is there a shorter one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of proving it by contradiction, you can prove it directly. Note that the following works for the limit approaching $x_0$ from either side:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x - x_0} &= \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{(f+g)(x) - (f+g)(x_0)}{x - x_0} - \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}\\
 &= \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{(f+g)(x) - (f+g)(x_0)}{x - x_0} - \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}.
\end{align*}
The latter two limits exist. You can also use $g = (f+g) - f$ to assure that $g$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Answer (score 3):

$g=f+g-f$
 I think this is enough...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First prove that if $a(x)$ is differentiable, then $c \cdot a(x)$ is differentiable for any constant $c$. Next, prove that if $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are differentiable, then $a(x)+b(x)$ is also differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

you can  prove that if $ h_1$ and $h_2$ are differntiable than $h_1+h_2$ is differentiable and that if $h$ is differentiable than $c\cdot h$ is differentiable 
(So the set of differentiable function in one point $x_0$ is a subspace of the Vectorial space of the continuos function in $x_0$)
In this case $g=(f+g)-f$ and so you have finished

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing a bit:

$F(x):= f(x)+g(x)$ ,

$G(x) : (-1)g(x)$ are differentiable  at $x=x_0$,

then $F(x) + G(x)$ is differentiable at $x=x_0.$

Used:

1) If $F$ and $G$ are differentiable then $F +G$ is differentiable.

2 If $H$ is differentiable then $-H$ is differentiable